# What is Nirvana? What is the practice leading to ultimate happiness in the light of one's own experience?

Tags: nirvana

What is the path or practice leading to ultimate happiness in the light of one's own practice which has lead you to achieving true happiness?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you explain "nirvana"?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3893/can-you-explain-nirvana)

Comment: That's not my question. I am searching someone who has attained nirvana but still here to answer my question. Regards.

Comment: Beyond your title of "what is nirvana in detail" you seem to be asking for someone to chat with (via comments) about happiness and life experience. Stack Exchange has a best answer format which would make such a discussion a poor fit for this site.

Comment: Asking for dialogue, not an answer

Comment: As I consider putting my question on hold I wish to ask 'is there any other way (available on this site in 'chat' section, related to my question ?

Comment: “Happiness is not an ideal of reason but of imagination”

Comment: I do not had words to put my question properly. I really really appreciate Sir Suminda for editing my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will jump into the fire of people's objections to posit that there is no achieving of true happiness. My intention is to reveal the truth that does exist beyond the bounds of our human expectation of ending suffering and attaining some new state or place where happiness is forever.
Zen does not look to attain or achieve a state but to awake to what is here. The Buddha replied when asked who he was: Awake. Any path can lead to awakening. The Buddha clearly defined the Middle Way, but it is not the only way. Even Buddhists who followed false teachers found awakening.
The intention is the key. If we intend to promote ourselves and our elusive and illusive personal self, we are bound to fail.
So to relate this to the Buddha's message here are the principles of the eight-fold path. Right intent or intention is here among them. 
http://www.buddha101.com/p_path.htm

> The eightfold path is Right Understanding, Right Intent, Right Speech,
>   Right Action, Right Livelihood, Right Effort, Right Mindfulness, and
>   Right Concentration.

Note that right does not mean right as opposed to wrong. Right can mean when things go in the flow or without resistance (same page further down)

> The meaning of Right has several aspects, and includes an ethical, and
>   a balanced, or middle way. When things go "right", we often experience
>   a special feeling inside which confirms that this is the correct
>   decision or action.

Further down the same page about intent

> Right Intent:
>
> The second step on the Eightfold Path is Right Intent. This is the
>   step where we become committed to the path. Right Understanding shows
>   us what life really is and what life’s problems are composed of, Right
>   Intent urges us to decide what our heart wants.
>
> Right Intent must come from the heart and involves recognising the
>   equality of all life and compassion for all that life, beginning with
>   yourself.
>
> Right Intent means persistence and a passion for the journey. Setting
>   out to climb a high mountain means you must understand the lay of the
>   land and the pitfalls, the other team members, and the equipment you
>   need. This is similar to Right Understanding. But you will only climb
>   the mountain if you really want to and have a passion for the climb.
>   This is Right Intent. The mountain we climb here is our journey though
>   life.
>
> To summarise, Right Understanding will eliminate ignorance. With Right
>   Intent and correct understanding, we then remove desire, which in turn
>   causes the suffering defined in the Four Noble Truths.

I rest here and leave it to those interested to find any other quotes of interest on that page. Thank you for the question.